# Override WinJS promises with native promises as a Chrome Extension content script?

Tags: typescript, webpack, promise, winjs, stenciljs

I have a Chrome Extension that injects a content script along with a library of components to display a UI (built using StencilJS). I've found on some sites that our UI does not display correctly given a new state.

After much debugging I found that the thing in common on these sites is WinJS. It seems that WinJS sets its on Promise implementation on `window.Promise`. This appears to be the cause of our UI issues.

Is there any way to enforce native promises for our code/Stencil library at build/run time to prevent us interfering with the page and vice versa? We're using Stencil's standard build configuration along with Webpack to bundle the code into a Chrome Extension format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native `Promise` constructor/object can be retrieved from:

```
(async _ => _)().constructor
```

So let your content script redefine `Promise` either as a global variable, or maybe as a local variable in a wrapper function, so it only affects that script:

```
var Promise = (async _ => _)().constructor;
```